# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, valueerror

```
    sp = int(input("the dp is $"))
    print(sp)
    while True: #make sure they only put number
        try:
            int(sp)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                float(sp)
            except ValueError:
                print("This is not a number. Please put a valid price.")
        print("Please enter a valid number")
    #This is to ensure that the customer is entering a valid variable, not too high or low
    if sp <=100: print("Your price is too low. Please enter a higher and valid price.")
    if sp >=10000: print("Your price is too high. Please enter a lower and valid price")
```

when I try to put too high or low numbers, the message error works but if i enter letters, the program says error.

Comment: Which error do you get, and what is the full traceback? And how do you ever get to the last two lines: your `while` loop has no way to end.

Comment: Yes, because you are using `sp = int(input("the dp is $")`, making your entire `while True` loop pointless. Remove the call to `int`, that's what the loop and `try-except` are for!

Answer (score 0):

```
sp = int(input("the dp is $"))
```

You're already defining the variable as an integer here.

Without the error message I can only speculate, but I image it already happens here, because a string can't be converted to int.

Answer (score -1):

Indentation is important. I think this is what you were trying to do? Also, since your input() was outside of the loop, when someone input an invalid number, it would just keep looping with that invalid number forever.

```
while True: #make sure they only put number
    sp = int(input("the dp is $"))
    print(sp)
    try:
        int(sp)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(sp)
        except ValueError:
            print("This is not a number. Please put a valid price.")

    #This is to ensure that the customer is entering a valid variable, not too high or low
    if sp <=100: print("Your price is too low. Please enter a higher and valid price.")
    elif sp >=10000: print("Your price is too high. Please enter a lower and valid price")
    else: print("Success")
```